# Dropbox php sdk library errors

Tags: api, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to set dropbox api up on this website http://wedapp.users34.interdns.co.uk/

I am using this library http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/

I am getting lots of issues i have contacted my host and they have confirmed that i have The OAuth extension installed.

Just keep getting lots of errors like below.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid
>   auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)' in
>   /home/wedapp/public_html/Dropbox/OAuth/PHP.php:73 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/wedapp/public_html/Dropbox/OAuth/PHP.php(73):
>   OAuth->fetch('https://api.dro...', Array, 'POST', Array) #1
>   /home/wedapp/public_html/Dropbox/API.php(97):
>   Dropbox_OAuth_PHP->fetch('https://api.dro...', Array, 'POST') #2
>   /home/wedapp/public_html/index.php(13):
>   Dropbox_API->getToken('info@isimpledes...', 'webdesigner1982') #3
>   {main} thrown in /home/wedapp/public_html/Dropbox/OAuth/PHP.php on
>   line 73

you can see the errors i am getting here. http://wedapp.users34.interdns.co.uk/

Any thing please guys.

Answer (score 0):

A 401 error means "Bad or expired token. This can happen if the user or Dropbox revoked or expired an access token. To fix, you should re-authenticate the user." ( https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api )

You will need to go through the app authentication process again to get a valid token.